# How many proceses does this pseudo code creates?

Tags: c, linux, fork

hey guys I have a problem for one of my operation system classes that ask me how many processes does this pseudo c code generates in Linux. thanks I'm still learning

```
n=72
int pid[n]; /* asume the content its inicialice in 0 */
int i;
for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ){  
    pid[i] = fork()
    if ( childpid == 0 ) { 
        if ( (pid[0] > 0) && (pid[n-1] == 0) ) {
            if(fork())
                fork();
        }
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Well I'm kinda confuse, cus i cant really execute the code and my logic is not the best, but i think it creates 72 processes from the father and then only in the first child and last one, it creates 2 each.
thanks  love u

Comment: Why can't you execute it?

Comment: What does this have to do with image processing?

Comment: I fixed a bunch of spelling mistakes but left the missing title case at the start of sentences.  Consider running your question through a spell checker next time.

Comment: The variable `childpid` is not initialized or set so I don't we can reason about the code as is.  The comment "assume content" is hokey.  Initialize the variable instead, as it's a vla, that requires a loop or memset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent process creates 72 children.

```
if ( childpid == 0 )
```

will succeed in all the child processes.

`(pid[0] > 0)` will be true in all child processes except the first one. In the first child, `pid[i] = fork();` assigns `0` to `pid[0]`. All the other children will inherit the parent's `pid` array, with all the preceding elements filled in with previous childrens' PIDs.

`pid[n-1] == 0` will be true in all child processes, since that array index isn't assigned until the last child is created, and the last child gets a copy of the array before it's assigned.

So the condition

```
if ( (pid[0] > 0) && (pid[n-1] == 0) )
```

succeeds in 71 child processes. Those 71 processes then execute

```
            if(fork())
                fork();
```

This creates two grandchild processes. `if (fork())` succeeds in the child process because `fork()` returns the PID if the first grandchild, then that child process executes `fork()` again to create a second grandchild.

So the total number of processes created is 72 children + 71 * 2 grandchildren = 214 processes.

Comment: Does childpid have a well defined value?

Comment: It's pseudo-code, I assumed it's the PID that was just returned from `fork()`.